# Strong-type new object after LINQ select statement

Tags: c#, linq

This is not a critical concept for me but I was just
wondering if I could strong-type a new object after `linq` `select` statement, rather than make it anonymous type, in `C#`. Here is an sample, defunct of course but speaks to the concept:

```
public class DisplayAddress { public int AddressId; public string ShortAddress; }

List<DisplayAddress> shortAddresses = 
  (from la in longAddresses
    join ca in customerAddresses
      on la.AddressId equals ca.AddressId
    where ca.CustomerId == selectedCustomer
  select new { new DisplayAddress() {AddressId = la.AddressId, ShortAddress = la.Line1 + " " + la.City + " " + la.State}}).Tolist<DisplayAddress>();
```

Comment: I think you're overthinking it.  just select new DisplayAddress{ AddressId = la.AddressId, ...}

Comment: Why are you creating an anonymous type instead of just selecting new `DisplayAddress`?

Comment: The `select new` statement shouldn't even compile. You are not declaring any member on the anonymous type

Comment: @Jeremy Holovacs  - I needed new typed object so I could pass it between methods and classes. The author of the accepted answer got the idea spot-on. In a larger scope, this code will supply collection to `AddRange()` method of a different collection.

Comment: @Matias Cicero  - you are right about not compiling - hence "defunct" in the question. The answer however get's everything right - just compiled it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Absolutely, you can use any expression in the `Select`, including one that creates a new object of a type that you defined. All you need to do is removing the outer `new`:

```
select new DisplayAddress {
    AddressId = la.AddressId
,   ShortAddress = la.Line1 + " " + la.City + " " + la.State
}).Tolist();
```

Note that anonymous types are strongly typed as well. In other words, if you do

```
select new {
    AddressId = la.AddressId
,   ShortAddress = la.Line1 + " " + la.City + " " + la.State
}).Tolist();
```

your anonymous type would have two strongly-typed fields called `AddressId` and `ShortAddress`. The only difference is that you would need to consume anonymous objects in the context where you create them in order to preserve strong typing. In other words, you would not be able to pass the results of anonymous `Select` to a non-generic function without using `dynamic`, `object`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Your example code was **really** close. You over-complicated a few things which were probably your downfall.

In your `select` clause, rather than defining a `new { new DisplayAddress() ... }` just do `new DisplayAddress()`. (You were effectively boxing your `DisplayAddress` in another unnecessary object. There's also the compiler error of not defining what the member name of that property was.)

At the end of your query, you were doing `Tolist<DisplayAddress>()`. Couple of issues:

- The method is `ToList()` and capitalization matters in C#. :)
- Because you specified `DisplayAddress` in your `Tolist<DisplayAddress>()` call, it was causing a compiler error because you can't convert your anonymous type to a strong type of `DisplayAddress`.

After you address all of these small issues, you come up with the following:

```
var shortAddresses = (from la in longAddresses
                      join ca in customerAddresses
                        on la.AddressId equals ca.AddressId
                      where ca.CustomerId == selectedCustomer
                      select new DisplayAddress() 
                      { 
                        AddressId = la.AddressId, 
                        ShortAddress = la.Line1 + " " + la.City + " " + la.State
                      }).ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks. The goal was to avoid using `var` type. Sorry for the capitalization - I wrote it in Notepad. dasblinkenlight caught my drift spot-on.

Comment: You can still not use `var` by replacing it with `List<DisplayAddress>`. I just find it more simple and more terse. (It also makes it so fellow readers don't have to scroll to view the code segment. :)